# restric access json data with grape and rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, ruby-grape

I have a json data in this address:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/apisearch
```

These json data are generated with grape gem https://github.com/intridea/grape:

```
class API_v1 < Grape::API
  version 'v1', :using => :path, :vendor => 'myapp', :format => :json
    get :apisearch do
      Object.search({query: "*#{params[:q]}*"}).map{ |object| {id: object.title, text: object.description } }
    end
 end
```

I have a search engine that get data from this address with [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/)

This is my coffescript file:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#query_txt').select2
    width: 'resolve'
    allowClear: true
    minimumInputLength: 2
    ajax:
      url: "api/v1/apisearch"
      dataType: 'json'
      data: (term, page) -> {q: term}
      results: (data, page) ->
        results: data
```

The script is working very fine, but I would like protect this address of external requests.

I don't want to allow a user if type `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/apisearch` can access to these data. Only can access to these data my internal search engine from my own application.

**How can I restric access data only to my own application from grape?**

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am new to grape and Rails but here is something that came to mind if you do not have to use grappa and can use Rails.

You can check the "requester" URL with Rails and if it originates from yourapplication.com you allow access otherwise deny.

Comment: Thank you, can you paste a example in your response?. I have made this same question on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-grape/ZvXBQD4bFms and Daniel Doubrovkine the grape creator say me that it's not possible. If you can paste a code solution would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: I added it there. Would be interested in learning how you decided to go about your problem.

Comment: Thank you Yuri, I have tried with https://github.com/udzura/rack-block but it is not possible from localhost. I don't know if is required with a real domain. If you know a fix with a real example, would be very useful for other users. Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok, I guess the consensus so far is that it is not practical to restrict via domain and via IP is an ok solution?

Comment: Via ip is a ok solution. So I'm searching a solution for this problem. I guess that is possible restrict the access to json data on url address only to own app. Thank you!